# Error: Could not stat() command file nagios.cmd

Tags: nagios

Good Folks,

I have a question on how to resolve the following error:

```
Error: Could not stat() command file '/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd'!

The external command file may be missing, Nagios may not be running, and/or Nagios may not be checking external commands.

An error occurred while attempting to commit your command for processing.
```

I don't want to disable SELINUX as that is what said in general as I believe it is a security risk to disable it.

Furthermore here is the information which is required to troubleshoot the issue.

```
[root@puppet local]# ls -l /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd 
prw-rw----. 1 nagios nagcmd 0 Jul  9 19:43 /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd
[root@puppet local]# ls -l /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/
total 0
prw-rw----. 1 nagios nagcmd 0 Jul  9 19:43 nagios.cmd
srw-rw----. 1 nagios nagcmd 0 Jul  9 19:43 nagios.qh
[root@puppet local]# ls -ld /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/
drwxrwsr-x. 2 nagios nagcmd 4096 Jul  9 19:43 /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/
[root@puppet local]# grep nag /etc/group
nagios:x:492:nagios
nagcmd:x:501:apache
[root@puppet local]#
```

Let me know if you need any further information.

Regards,
Jim

Comment: [root@puppet etc]# cat cgi.cfg |grep authorized
authorized_for_system_information=nagios
authorized_for_configuration_information=nagios
authorized_for_system_commands=nagios
authorized_for_all_services=nagios
authorized_for_all_hosts=nagios
authorized_for_all_service_commands=nagios
authorized_for_all_host_commands=nagios
#authorized_for_read_only=user1,user2
[root@puppet etc]#

Comment: Modified group still no use:
[root@puppet ~]# grep nag /etc/group
nagios:x:492:nagios
nagcmd:x:501:apache,nagios
[root@puppet ~]#